# Caliburn Micro - Show Screens simultaniously

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm aware that I can switch through Screens if I do the following:

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive
{
  public void ShowFirstScreen()
  {
    ActivateItem(new FirstViewModel());
  }

  public void ShowSecondScreen()
  {
    ActivateItem(new SecondViewModel());
  }

}
```

**ShellView.xaml for OneActive**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
```

But I want to show those Screens simultaniously. So when changing from **OneActive** to **AllActive** there is no Screen visible anymore.

I know that I can show these Screens if I use an ItemsControl

**ShellView.xaml for AllActive**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But I want to place them randomly within my ShellView.xaml.

How to do that?

How to access them? I want to place them like UserControls within my ShellView.xaml.

```
<Grid>
<ContenControl x:Name="Item1 or even the ViewModel name"/>
<ContenControl x:Name="Item2 or even the ViewModel name"/>
...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your shellview.xaml

```
<ContentControl x:Name="NameOfViewModel" />
```

In your ShellViewModel.cs

```
 public NameOfViewModel NameOfViewModel {
   get;set;  // auto for brevity 
 }
```

instantiate the viewmodel in your choice of OnInitialized(), OnActivated() or in the Ctor... Basically if the ContentControl name matches a property you will get a screen, once the viewmodel is instantiated.  No match no screen.

Comment: Thanks. Why does this not work if I change the name of the ViewModel from NameOfViewModel to _NameOfViewModel? Is a "__" not allowed within the x:Name attribute?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752290%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  Has to conform to the XamlGrammar and I don't believe having `_` prefixed will work.

Comment: Tried same way as mentioned above , its initialize Viewmodel constructor but not showing View /initialize View constructor.